# Read username from GoogleSignInAccount ( Google Fit Android API)

Tags: google-fit, googlesigninaccount

I'm using the Google Fit Android API to retrieve fitness data and it all works like a charm. I want to also access the name of the currently logged in user , which should be accessible by GoogleSignInAccount .getDisplayName();

I already asked this question but unfortunately didn't get any replies, and I cant figure it out with the documentation.

Example code:

```
 //Create a FitnessOptions instance, declaring the data types and access type (read and/or write) your app needs:
        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_SLEEP_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();


        //Get an instance of the Account object to use with the API:
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

        if (acct != null) {
            loggedInUser = account.getDisplayName();
        }
```

The problem is acct.getDisplayname().getGrantedScopes works like a charm, and I see the granted scope. When I try to read .getDisplayName I always get NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use another way of logging in...

I now use this to configure sign in options and access :

```
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()
        .build();


mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Then we start the sign in intent:

```
  Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 000000);
```

And now we handle the result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == 000000) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

Tips: Make sure to use ApiException.class from Google and not AWS